# iOS - Pass Data from one viewController to another using tabBarController in xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, xib

I have a requirement where I have to pass a string value from one viewController to another on button click. I also need to switch from current viewController to secondViewController using tabBarController. I tried:

**FirstViewController.h**

#import "SecondViewController.h"

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) SecondViewController *secondController;
```

**FirstViewController.m**

```
-(IBAction)go:(id)sender
{
   self.secondController.itemText=@"Demo Text";
   self.tabBarController.selectedIndex=1; //say secondViewController index is 1
}
```

**SecondViewController.h**

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *itemText;
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
  -(void) viewWillAppear (BOOL) animated
    {
       NSLog(@"Comes from FirstViewController: %@",self.itemText);
    }
```

Though it switches the viewController but it prints blank. What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your first view controller's "`secondController`" property is not the same object pointed to in the tab bar controller.

The correct thing to do is to access your "`SecondViewController`" from the [view controller array property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/viewControllers) in the tab bar.

That is to say, something like this:

```
-(IBAction)go:(id)sender
{
    SecondViewController *secondVC = (SecondViewController *)[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex: 1];
    secondVC.itemText=@"Demo Text";
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex=1; 
}
```

Comment: App is crushing. Getting error:

`-[UINavigationController setitemText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: I dropped the first (and wrong) line of my code and now everything should be correct.  If you set an Xcode breakpoint on the lines of your "`go`" action, is `secondVC` the view controller you were expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Working fine for me

```
-(IBAction)go:(id)sender
{
SecondViewController *secondVC = (SecondViewController *)[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex: 1];
    secondVC.itemText=@"Demo Text";
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex=1;
}
```